# Check out from a remote SVN repository TO a remote location?

Tags: svn, ssh

Is there a way with SVN to check out from a remote repository to another remote location rather than my local file system? Something like:

```
svn co http://myrepository/svn/project ssh me@otherlocation.net:/var/www/project
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you could do:

```
ssh me@other.net 'svn co http://repository/svn/project /var/www/project'
```

This takes advantage of the fact that ssh lets you execute a command remotely.

Comment: I tested it myself just to be sure, and it works for me, so let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. If you want to copy a repository, look into [svnsync](http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/notes/svnsync.txt).

Comment: Syncing repositories is not the same as checking out a repository.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Subversion with [SSHFS](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html).