# Checkout from SVN to remote location with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, ssh, svn-checkout

I am in the need to set up eclipse in a way that I can connect to a SVN and checkout projects or files to a remote location. The remote location is Linux-based, the clients work with windows.

I read a few threads and it seems that it works on console with ssh+svn. But I am struggling badly to make this scenario run in eclipse.

Any hints? I appreciate your help.

Philipp

Comment: Why do you need to check out to a remote location? The point of SVN is that you have a *local* working copy. Is this for deployment? In that case, there might be better options.

Comment: @Roger Lipscombe +1 , maybe op can run "svn co URL" via ssh rather then from eclipse.However, still don't understand why OP need such thing

Comment: @rkosegi in which case, they want this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159152/check-out-from-a-remote-svn-repository-to-a-remote-location

Comment: You need to _check out_ to a remote location? That doesn't exactly seem like a scenario a CVS is built for. Don't you need to _export_ to that location? In fact different SVN implementations could handle metadata completely different. Even different versions of SVN could cause problems this way. Anyway - any chance to access the remote location in a way transparent to your client's OS like a network share (SMB), FTP or similar?

Comment: Because local development is not possible. The ERP system is not able to support that. So we need to develop on the server. And now I want svn with that. That's why.

Comment: Or, more to the point, why do you need to do this from inside Eclipse? Surely this is a Continuous Deployment issue? In which case, you want something like Hudson or TeamCity...

Answer (score 1):

Your question sounds to me that you try to solve something, that we don't know yet. So I speculate here a little bit, and I will change my answer if the question gives indication that I was wrong.

- (Part of your) development has to live on the server, so there are resources you have to use during development, which are necessary for development.
- Possibly these resources are (only) necessary for testing (unit tests?), or for functional tests.
- You have experience with Eclipse and want to use that.

So here are sketches of possible solutions that may work for you.

### Using Eclipse on the server

- You install an appropriate eclipse distro on the linux machine you have to develop on.
- You install locally e.g. Cygwin with the XWin packages that allow you to start an X-windows server locally.
- You open up an xterm locally (just to get the display variable correct).
- You start from that xterm the eclipse installed on the Linux machine: `ssh <user-id>@<ip-of-linux-server> <path to eclipse> -display $DISPLAY`

#### Pros and cons

- + You work on the machine and have the display locally.
- + You are able to checkout directly on the machine, no need of a local copy.
- - Your are not able to work without the connection to the Linux machine.

### Using Eclipse locally

There are two variants, and both are valuable:

- Have the sources on the server (only)
- Have the sources locally

### Sources on server, Eclipse locally

The easiest way is to mount the file system of the server, so you have access to them locally through a different drive letter. Ask your system administrator how that could be accomplished.

#### Pros and cons

- + Everything works as normal.
- + You don't have to install Subversion on the server.
- - Latency for the remote file system may be annoying.
- - You are only able to work with network connection to the server.

### Sources locally, Eclipse locally

That is the normal way to do it. Install Eclipse with Subversion plugin as usual, checkout from the repository, work locally (even disconnected), commit your changes.

You are then able to test by doing a checkout on the server, build the system there, and do your unit and integration tests there.

#### Pros and cons

- + Easier to install and maintain.
- - No tests during development without a build process in between.
- - Tests can only be done with commited code, not with changes that are not commited.

### My recommendation

I like the solution best with Eclipse on the server, so you use everything that is available on the server, and Eclipse under Linux is totally the same as under Windows. You don't have any steps in between for doing tests, everything is done locally (on the server).

See as well the following questions (and answers):

- [Is it possible to work on remote files in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473154/is-it-possible-to-work-on-remote-files-in-eclipse)

PS: What I forgot: I think `svn+ssh` is just a different protocol of Subversion to do the checkout, update and commit. It is in no way different to using the protocols `file://`, `svn://`, `http://` or even `https://`.